# How to change li class to li id's in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have installed the flexslider plugin, [click here](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties) which is working fine, However there's a small element in the JS i want to change, which is the slide identifiers [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/product-details.php) 
At present flexslider creates `ul` classes field called `flex-control-nav` and `flex-control-paging` which creates an `li` class called `flex-active` for the page identifiers These fields are not in my HTML.

Is there a way i can get the JS to create an individual ID for the identifiers as i want to style each identifier differently. I would paste the code but there's quite alot of it. If you inspect element the link above, the main flexsilder JS is in flexsilder.js

Comment: you could just run a script to add incremental id's to all the lis with that class

Comment: and how is that done? sorry i'm pants with Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the following worked me...

```
<!-- Inside of slider element -->
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
...
</ul>
<ul class="custom-controls">
<li><a href="#">Slide One</a></li>
...
</ul>
</div>

//Inside .flexslider() properties
manualControls: '.custom-controls li a'


<!-- Outside of slider element - must use controlsContainer property -->
<div class"flex-container">
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
  ...
</ul>
 </div>
 <ul class="custom-controls">
  <li><a href="#">Slide One</a></li>
   ...
 </ul>
 </div>
 //Inside .flexslider() properties
  manualControls: '.custom-controls li a',
  controlsContainer: '.flex-container'
```

Answer (score 0):

in the footer or header, you could throw in something like this after wherever you are running that other script or you could just throw it in that script if it uses jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.flex-control-paging').each(function(key, value){
         $(this).attr('id', 'id_name_'+key);
      });
   });
</script>
```

Now a couple of things.  This assumes youre already loading jquery on the page.  Also, I think that flex-control-paging is the class thats on all your li tags but if not substitute it.

Comment: Cheers, i've added that snippet of code into my footer however the JS is still creating a class...?

Comment: ya, the class is being used by the jquery to add the id to each.

Comment: whatever plug in youre using is probably using the class for either styling or functionality so you probably can't get away with removing it.  But now that there are ids there you can override the styles set by the class.

Comment: are there ids, my inspector isn't picking anything up?

Comment: check your console to see if my script is throwing an error, otherwise its attaching the ids to the wrong element.  should be the class of the li tags you want the id attached to